# NameError: global name 'BluetoothSocket' is not defined

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I am trying to create a program on my raspberry pi that is accepting a bluetooth connection from an android device. But the build always fails. This is my code:

```
from bluetooth import *

def initServer():
server_sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
server_sock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)

uuid = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"

advertise_service(server_sock, "Echo Server",
 service_id = uuid,
 service_classes = [ uuid, SERIAL_PORT_CLASS ],
 profiles = [ SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE ]
)
return server_sock

def getClientConnection(server_sock):
 print "Waiting for connection" 
 client_sock, client_info = server_sock.accept()
 print "accepted connection from ", client_info
 return client_sock

def manageConnection(socket):
 try:
   while True:
     data = socket.recv(1024)
     if len(data) == 0: break
     print "received [%s]" % data
     socket.send("Echo from Pi: [%s]\n" % data)
 except IOError:
   pass
server=initServer()
while  True:
client=getClientConnection(server)
manageConnection(client)
client.close()
server.close()
print "terminating..."
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bluetooth.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bluetooth import *
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/bluetooth.py", line 33, in <module>
    server=initServer()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/bluetooth.py", line 4, in initServer
    server_sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
NameError: global name 'BluetoothSocket' is not defined
```

python-bluetooth is already installed. But what could cause this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Fix your indentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call your file bluetooth.py, it will be confused with the module you're trying to import.

Also take a look at your indentation, hopefully it's different from what you submitted.